# Accessing ASP HiddenField in javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have been searching through here and google for a few days now, trying to figure out why I cannot get the value of a hiddenfield variable in javascript.  When accessed, the value is returned as undefined.
I have an ASP HiddenField inside an UpdatePanel which is part of a custom user control in a .aspx web page (standard issue).

In my user control, I need to get the .Value of the HiddenField (hdnServer) in javascript after setting it in C#.  But for some reason the following is not getting the correct value.

The MessageBox in the C# code returns the correct value (the code here has test values), but when accessed in javascript is undefined.

userControl.ascx:

```
//this function is called when the timer created in document.ready() elapses
//returns the correct hdnServer value in the check. 
    var checkHdn = function () {
        var temp = document.getElementById("<%=hdnServer.ClientID%>").value;
        temp = temp.toString();
        if (temp != "") {
            $('#LoadingViewer').hide();
            clearInterval(checkSrv);

            //enable start button
            $('#startBtn').attr("Enabled", "true");
        }
    };

  function RdpConnect() {

                //serverName = undefined here.  should be ip address when set in c# 
                var serverName = document.getElementById("<%= hdnServer.ClientID %>").value;
                alert(serverName);
                if (serverName != "") {
                    MsRdpClient.Server = serverName;
                }
            };
```

userControl.ascx.cs code-behind:

```
public partial class userControl : System.Web.UI.UserControl
    {
        System.Timers.Timer timer; 

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timer = new System.Timers.Timer(5000);
            timer.Start();
        }

        protected void testOnTick(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
                hdnServer.Value = "test value";
                startBtn.Enabled = true;
                timer.Enabled = false;
        }
    }
```

Here is the asp for HiddenField just in case: userControl.ascx:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" />
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Always">
    <Triggers>
         <!--trigger not used  -->
       <!-- <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Timer1" EventName="Tick" />-->
    </Triggers>
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnServer" runat="server" />
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" Text="Loading, please wait." CssClass="loading" runat="server"
            Font-Size="XX-Large" />
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Thank you for any advice in advance!

EDIT:  messagebox removed..
Here is rendered html:  http://pastie.org/3122247

Comment: What does the rendered HTML look like?

Comment: Why you add MessageBox.Show? Remove it.

Comment: It has nothing to do with hidden fields, that for sure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to set ClientIDMode if you want to make it simple:

```
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" Id="hidServer"/>

<script type="text/javascript">
  alert($("#hidServer").val());
</script>
```

Or, use the ClientID property if you don't set ClientIDMode:

```
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" Id="hidServer"/>

<script type="text/javascript">
  alert($("<%= hidServer.ClientID %>").val());
</script>
```

Comment: I get an error in HiddenField stating there no property exists called ClientIDMode in it.  <% hdnServer.ClientID %> was the original way I tried it.  returns undefined.

Comment: ClientIDMode is set on the control, look at the code I posted.

Answer (score 3):

User controls have always been a strange issue for referencing using js and then master pages to go along with it.

For the hidden field do this:

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hdnServer" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" />
```

in the js, do this:

```
var serverName = document.getElementById('hdnServer').value;
```

Comment: I'm getting an exception stating that HiddenField doesn't have the ClientIDMode property..

Comment: Ah...that is new to asp 4.0, guessing that is not what you are using. You need to load the page and see what id is being given to the hiddenfield using view-source. you will end up with a "master-page_userControl_hdnServer" id that you need to put into the js like: var serverName = document.getElementById('ContentPlaceHolder1_ucWebUserControl_hdnServer').value;

Comment: Ok. I got the view-source id and tried using that and got an undefined error.  I've also tried switching the solution to 4.0 and setting clientIDMode to static and it it returns an empty string "".  Is this a known problem?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var temp = $('#mytestcontrol_hdnServer').val();
```

Comment: this returns an empty value.  ""

Comment: I looked at your code again and saw that you set the value of the hidden control 5 seconds AFTER the control has loaded using a timer.  At that point, the page has ALREADY been rendered and sent to the browser.  As a test, try initializing the hidden control to a value immediately on load.

Comment: I set the value of hdnServer on the Page_Load and it worked.  The value was correctly received when I used var temp = document.getElementById(“<%=hdnServer.ClientID%>”).value;  Why is this?  Thanks for the help.

Comment: As I pointed out, when the timer fires, it is too late.  The page has already been rendered and sent to the browser.

Answer (score 1):

you need to use `'` not `"`
like:

```
var serverName = document.getElementById('<%= hdnServer.ClientID %>').value;
```

be careful don't use `"`. You have only use `'`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
var temp = $('#hdnServer').val();
```

Instead of :

```
var temp = document.getElementById("<%=hdnServer.ClientID%>").value;
```

Also change this:

```
var serverName = document.getElementById("<%= hdnServer.ClientID %>").value;
```

To this:

```
var serverName = $('#hdnServer').val();
```

Comment: I still get that temp and serverName = undefined when I do this.

Comment: I would suggest you inspect your html code with either firebug in Firefox or Chrome to see the exact element `ID` but before you can remove the `MessageBox.Show()`;

Comment: element id in rendered html is: id="mytestcontrol_hdnServer".  when I use this in var temp=$("<%=mytestcontrol_hdnServer%>").val() it throws an exception saying the control doesn't exist..

Comment: ok then you can access that via jQuery as `var temp = $('#mytestcontrol_hdnServer').val()` or plain javascript as `var temp = document.getElementById('mytestcontrol_hdnServer').value`.