# In IE11 document.getelementbyid is not working?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11, hidden-field

```
function Get() {
 {
   var hidvalue = document.getElementById('hid');

     }

<asp:HiddenField ID="hid" runat="server" />
```

I have seen previous answers in stackoverflow but it is not helping me.    the above lines in javascript is not working(value is not getting) in ie edge mode.

Comment: Replace it with what, and why? If it's not working, it probably has nothing to do with `getElementById`

Comment: I'm not sure but should it be not something like this: `document.getElementById(<% hid.ClientID %>);`. `hid` is a asp.net component and it has a different clientID and serverID.

Comment: Look at the `hid` element in the browser. My guess is that WebForms is prepending something to that id and that's why you're not finding it.

Comment: @adeneo I checked the same javascript in ie5 mode.There we are getting value.But in IE11 value is coming as null.

Comment: @neilsimp1 When i inspect with ie5 mode we are getting value in input type but in ie11 input type in not having values

Comment: @vicky try logging `hidvalue` in console. Also refer following [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8721313/accessing-asp-hiddenfield-in-javascript)